# Moving from SDK level 23 to 27 breaks my app

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently upgraded a workstation and loaded Android Studio 3.0.1, which defaults to Android SDK Platform 27. Thought I'd migrate app from Android SDK Platform 23 to SDK Platform 27

Android Studio is helpful with this migration, suggests all the right parameters updated as below;

```
compileSdkVersion       23      --->    27
buildToolsVersion       23.0.1  --->    27.0.3

Gradle version          2.14.1  --->    4.1
Android Plugin Version  2.2.2   --->    3.0.1

minSdkVersion           9       --->    14
targetSdkVersion        23      --->    27
```

Also had to add Google maven repository and update the com.android.support libraries as below;

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1          --->    27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1    --->    27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1     --->    27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1 --->    27.0.2'
```

All seems good so far, builds APK and installs on device just fine but app crashed

I appreciate the potential vastness of the possible issues, so I'd just like to ask;

1. Notwithstanding my dodgy code, is there a methodology I can follow so I don't miss anything..?

As suspected, there's a coding error I got away with on v23 but isn't tolerated on v27

In the past I've been able to reference "username" on the navigation bar header directly from onCreate method in MainActivity without error at SDK level 23 like this

```
    rUsername = findViewById(R.id.username);
```

Android Studio on API level 27 doesn't detect any errors, project compiles into an APK fine, but the app crashes with a NullPointerException because rUsername never gets initialised

This is a well documented issue resolved in posts by @Bereket Gobeze, @Farmaan Elahi, @ianhanniballake, @RmK et al. and fix is as follows using getHeaderView

```
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    if (navigationView != null) {
        setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        rUsername = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.username);
    }
```

I can confirm that this now works properly, app compiles and runs fine. Project must be resynched for username on navigation header to be available for selection in Android Studio

Hope that might be useful for someone else

Comment: You say that "it just doesn't work" despite compiling and loading onto the device, so the Gradle build process seems happy (which is frequently the first to complain about something being the wrong version).

How do you know it is not working? What shows up in the LOGCAT window?

Comment: One thought is you could do a "Analyze -> Inspect Code ..." and see if lint check shows something surprising. Maybe you upgraded past a point that requires a code change that android-lint is aware of. Just a thought.

Comment: Did you change the version of Firebase that you are using? The latest version required some code changes but I am surprised that your project would still compile in that case...

Comment: I doubt this is it since your program builds without error, but the firebase UI version change to 3.0 was breaking : https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/docs/upgrade-to-3.0.md.  ("This document outlines the key breaking changes made between versions 2.3.0 and 3.0.0 as well as suggested upgrade paths.")

Comment: Your logcat indicates null pointer exception at line 438, MainActivity.java, in initAppVariables. What does that code contain?

    Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException:
            com.support.android.powerpage.MainActivity.initAppVariables (MainActivity.java:438)

Comment: rMobile TextView is not found in your view for some reason.. it is null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164722/discussion-between-mike-and-rangi).

Comment: There is no panacea, you must be more specific about which problem you actually have.